# How can I fix this error to update ubuntu 10.04 lts

Tags: 10.04, updates

```
Error Type: 
Error Value: installArchives() failed
File : /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/apt/aptBackend.py, line 2216, in main()
File : /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/apt/aptBackend.py, line 2213, in main run(args,options.single)
File : /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/apt/aptBackend.py, line 2175, in run backend.dispatcher(args)
File : /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/packagekit/backend.py, line 710, in dispatcher self.dispatch_command(args[0], args[1:])
File : /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/packagekit/backend.py, line 657, in dispatch_command self.update_packages(only_trusted, package_ids)
File : /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/apt/aptBackend.py, line 202, in _locked_cache func(*args, **kwargs)
File : /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/apt/aptBackend.py, line 1230, in update_packages self._commit_changes()
File : /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/apt/aptBackend.py, line 1842, in _commit_changes PackageKitInstallProgress(self, install_range))
File : /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apt/deprecation.py, line 103, in deprecated_function return func(*args, **kwds)
File : /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apt/cache.py, line 381, in commit raise SystemError("installArchives() failed")
```

How can I fix this error to update Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.broken
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1816855)